# Splitting single array into multiple arrays for mysql data insert

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to split a load of data from a text-area that is tab delimited data into multiple arrays.

The process is: 
Pasta data into textarea 
Post textarea to insert.php 
Preg_replace Tabs with commas 
Explode on comma 
print_r

Date sample being used is: 
`Dr S Findlay   1234567890  Mickey  Mouse   01/01/2001  Elective Waiting    02/02/2002 00:00    Dr one  Day Case    03/03/2003 00:00    On Medical Advice   Usual Place of Residence`

The result I get from this is: 
`Array ( [0] => Dr S Findlay [1] => 1234567890 [2] => Mickey [3] => Mouse [4] => 01/01/2001 [5] => Elective Waiting [6] => 02/02/2002 00:00 [7] => Dr one [8] => Day Case [9] => 03/03/2003 00:00 [10] => On Medical Advice [11] => Usual Place of Residence [12] => )`

This works well and is inserted perfectly into mysql database. However when I use a full data range which can be anything from 2x to 50x the data amount exampled above it displays differently:

More realistic data sample: 
`Dr S Findlay   1234567890  Mickey  Mouse   01/01/2001  Elective Waiting    02/02/2002 00:00    Dr one  Day Case    03/03/2003 00:00    On Medical Advice   Usual Place of Residence

Dr Peter    1234557890  Mickey1 Mouse1  01/01/2003  Waiting 02/02/2014 00:00    Dr one  Waiting Case

Dr Nail 1234569990  Mickey2 Mouse2  01/01/2009  Emergencey  02/02/2018 00:00    Dr one  Emergencey              29/05/2018`

Result: 
`Array ( [0] => Dr S Findlay [1] => 1234567890 [2] => Mickey [3] => Mouse [4] => 01/01/2001 [5] => Elective Waiting [6] => 02/02/2002 00:00 [7] => Dr one [8] => Day Case [9] => 03/03/2003 00:00 [10] => On Medical Advice [11] => Usual Place of Residence [12] => Dr Peter [13] => 1234557890 [14] => Mickey1 [15] => Mouse1 [16] => 01/01/2003 [17] => Waiting [18] => 02/02/2014 00:00 [19] => Dr one [20] => Waiting Case [21] => [22] => [23] => [24] => Dr Nail [25] => 1234569990 [26] => Mickey2 [27] => Mouse2 [28] => 01/01/2009 [29] => Emergencey [30] => 02/02/2018 00:00 [31] => Dr one [32] => Emergencey [33] => [34] => [35] => [36] => 29/05/2018 )`

What I want to do (but cannot figure out how to do) is split this into arrays so that each line of data (13 columns not always with data in) displays like this so that I can insert all of it into mysql in one go. Im not sure if this will work so please correct me if it won't.

What I want it to look like: 
`Array ( [0] => Dr S Findlay [1] => 1234567890 [2] => Mickey [3] => Mouse [4] => 01/01/2001 [5] => Elective Waiting [6] => 02/02/2002 00:00 [7] => Dr one [8] => Day Case [9] => 03/03/2003 00:00 [10] => On Medical Advice [11] => Usual Place of Residence [12] => )`


`Array ( [0] => Dr Peter [1] => 1234557890 [2] => Mickey1 [3] => Mouse1 [4] => 01/01/2003 [5] => Waiting [6] => 02/02/2014 00:00 [7] => Dr one [8] => Waiting Case [9] => [10] => [11] => [12] => )`



`Array ( [0] => Dr Nail [1] => 1234569990 [2] => Mickey2 [3] => Mouse2 [4] => 01/01/2009 [5] => Emergencey [6] => 02/02/2018 00:00 [7] => Dr one [8] => Emergencey [9] => [10] => [11] => [12] => 29/05/2018 )`

As I then presume I can give each part of the array an name `$forename = $area[2] ;` then use that to insert to the correct field of my database?

Sorry if this doesn't make sense - Or if I'm barking up the wrong tree. All & any advice, help or information is appreciated. Thanks AJ

Comment: Not sure if your approach is very safe and practical, but you can use `array_chunk()` to split an array into segments.

Comment: Please edit your question. It is very hard to read/understand. Try to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @NigelRen it is only accessible on the local network so security is not a concern. Thank you for your comment re array_chuck I will take a look.

Comment: The main thing is more about will it work consistently, with user input it only takes a slight typo to make a difference, using this method your data could be all over the place.

Comment: @NigelRen its copy and paste from an email so no typing is involved. I've half gotten it to work with `array_chunk()` however now need to figure out how to post each array back dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Hello Brother you explanation is quite confusing but as you 
described you **Working Process** in start so on the basis of that i 
like to suggest you below code. Have a try.

**NOT SURE WILL WORK BUT WORTH OF TRY**

```
<?php
     // explode by tab
     $tabbedContent = 'Dr   S   Findlay 1234567890  Mickey  Mouse   01/01/2001  Elective Waiting    02/02/2002 00:00    Dr  one Day Case    03/03/2003 00:00    On  Medical Advice  Usual   Place   of  Residence';

      echo '<pre>';
       var_dump(explode("\t", $tabbedContent));
      echo '</pre>';
  ?>
```

at least this may short your process.

[image]